# Which bikes were live on December 8?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL (MySql) and I got stuck with this problem with one of my assignments and couldn't get answer from anyone or searching online about the subject. The question goes like:

> Which bikes were live (`is_live = TRUE`) on December 8? (Display only `bike_id`).
>   Note: The Table does not have a row entry for December 8, and that is as intended
>
> ```
> Name        Type      Description
> id          int       LOG ID(PK)
> bike_id     int       id of the bike
> is_live     boolean   flag to indicate whether bike is live (TRUE/FALSE)
> updated_on  Date      Date on which status of bike was updated
> ```
>
> BIKE_LIVE_LOG table:
>
> ```
> id  bike_id     is_live   updated_on  
> 1      1        TRUE      2018-12-01
> 2      2        TRUE      2018-12-01
> 3      3        TRUE      2018-12-01
> 4      3        FALSE     2018-12-02
> 5      2        FALSE     2018-12-05
> 6      3        TRUE      2018-12-10
> ```

I couldn't move forward with the question as I am not even getting the approach for it with my current knowledge.

I have used this query to generate the the `last_update_date` grouped by each `bike_id`.

```sql
select bll.bike_id, max(bll.updated_on) as last_update_date
from bike_live_log as bll
where bll.updated_on <= '2018-12-08'
group by bll.bike_id;
```

The output will be 1.

Comment: You need to bring id into it since updated_on could contain true and false on same day.

Comment: You need to display `bike_id`s that [do have](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) a TRUE entry dated before December 8 [and](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and) [do not have](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) a FALSE entry dated later [than that](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html), but earlier than December 8.

Comment: If I add `id` to this query ,it does not returns the desired `id` rather 1,2,3...so on.

Comment: @GSerg, I get the logic now , but I am unable to write query for the same.

Comment: You might want to solve a related poblem first: for each bike_id find the most recent entry.

Comment: @wallenborn , I already mentioned the code for the same in my post .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement can be expressed more data-centrically as *find bikes whose last known status on or before Dec 8 was live*.

This is one way (IMHO the most readable way) to express that in SQL:

```
select bike_id
from bike_live_log bll
where updated_on = (
    select max(updated_on)
    from bike_live_log
    where bike_id = bll.bike_id
    and updated_on <= '2018-12-08'
)
and is_live
```

The [(corelated) subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) finds the date of the last update on or before Dec 8 for the current row of the outer query. If there's no such row, `null` will be returned, which won't match any rows from the outer query so, only bikes that have data  on or before Dec 8 will be returned.

Comment: This is a nice solution but doesn't account for multiple updates on the same day, assuming that's possible in the original question.

Comment: @Thomas you have raised as interesting point. Since the granularity of `updated_on` is only `date`, if there were multiple updates on the same day with different statuses there would be no way to know which update was last, which would result in an indeterminable status for that day. If there were multiple updates on the last day on or before Dec 8, this query would return the same `bike_id` once for each `is_live = TRUE` row on that date, which could be addressed by adding `distinct` to the query. But because the true status is indeterminable, it seems reasonable to disregard this situation.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to help you get to the last step. You're really, really close!

You were correct in going down the road of finding the most recent `updated_on` date for each `bike_id`. It doesn't matter how many times a bike has been turned on or off; you really only care about the most recent status prior to the date you're interested in.

With your current query, you already know when each `bike_id` was last updated prior to December 8th.

Next, you can use that information to find out what the `is_live` value was for each of those `bike_id` values as of that `last_update_date`.

You can do that by using your existing query as a sub-query, or a CTE if you prefer, and join back to your main table again. Your `JOIN` criteria will be `bike_id` to `bike_id` *and* `updated_on` to `last_update_date`. By joining on the dates, you'll only return a single record for each `bike_id`, and that record will be the one you're interested in.

After you have your `JOIN` put together, you'll just need to add a `WHERE` clause to limit your result set to the rows where `is_live = 'TRUE'`, which will return just `bike_id` of `1`.

Comment: @EricLeschinski, thank you for the feedback. In other situations, I've posted finished code to homework questions, but based on the OP's comments here it seemed he really wanted to be able to figure it out, as opposed to having an answer handed to him. I see from answers that have been posted since mine that the community has done a nice job of explaining the "why" to accompany their code, which is good. Here's hoping your edit wards off subsequent flags, and thanks for not voting to delete. My apologies for having a "meta-esque" conversation in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

Here is the MySQL code you need:

```
SELECT bike_id FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM bikes 
    WHERE updated_on < '20181209'
    ORDER BY updated_on DESC, id DESC
  ) AS sub 
  GROUP BY bike_id
) AS sub2
WHERE is_live = true
```

### Why does this work?

We need to break down the question a little bit. I like to start from a position of "how can I get the information I need in a format that makes sense to me (as a human)?".

So the first thing I did was to get a list of all bikes with `updated_on` dates before the 9th Dec (i.e. were updated on the 8th Dec or before). I also ordered this by `updated_on` field so I (as a human) could easily see the "latest" record which will tell me the most recent status of each bike on or before the 8th Dec:

```
SELECT * FROM bikes 
WHERE updated_on < '20181209'
ORDER BY updated_on DESC, id DESC
```

From this I can see there are 5 records of bike status changes before the 9th Dec. I can easily see that for each bike there are multiple "update" records, but I can now start from the top of the list and each bike id I encounter is the status on the 8th Dec.

Additionally I included an order_by for the record id. This is necessary because there could be multiple updates per day. The date itself won't tell us which of those updates was the latest ON THE SAME DAY, so we use the ID to determine that. (assuming it's chronologically incremental).

Now we have a list of all statuses and bike ids in the database before the 9th Dec we need to limit this to only one record per bike. This is easy, we can wrap the original query with a new query with a Group By directive on the bike_id.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM bikes 
  WHERE updated_on < '20181209'
  ORDER BY updated_on DESC, id DESC
) AS sub 
GROUP BY bike_id
```

Group By in MySQL selects the first record it comes across for each group. We have already ordered the list by `date` and `id` in the original query, so the first record for each `bike_id` will be the latest status for that bike as of the 8th Dec.

Now, all that's left for us to do is to select the `bike_id` and filter out non-live bikes by using `WHERE is_live = true` on this latest query. That's how we end up with the query at the start of this answer:

```
SELECT bike_id FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM bikes 
    WHERE updated_on < '20181209'
    ORDER BY updated_on DESC, id DESC
  ) AS sub 
  GROUP BY bike_id
) AS sub2
WHERE is_live = true
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
bike_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN last_live_date <= '2018-12-08' AND ( last_not_live_date < last_live_date OR last_not_live_date IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS final_status
FROM
(
SELECT
    bike_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN is_live = TRUE THEN updated_on END) AS last_live_date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN is_live = FALSE THEN updated_on END) AS last_not_live_date
FROM `BIKE_LIVE_LOG`
WHERE updated_on <= '2018-12-08'
GROUP BY bike_id
) AS a
GROUP BY bike_id
HAVING final_status = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with A as (select * from bike_live_log
where updated_on <= '2018-12-08'),
B as (select bike_id,max(updated_on) as updated from A
     group by bike_id)
     select A.bike_id from A inner join B
     on A.updated_on = B.updated
     where is_live = True;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.